# JS: Adding style dependent on class exist in siblings child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, siblings

I've had a look at related answers but none are what I am looking for... I think. Apologies if I am duplicating a question.

This HTML is used many times on a page, within a product box and is displayed on a product category page.

```
<div class"all-buttons-container">
    <div class="button1-container">
        <a class="button1">text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button2-container">
        <a class="button2 **hidden**">text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this (much simplified) HTML I have a container which houses 2 siblings.
- Each sibling contains an anchor.

- The button containers are always visible.
- Sometimes, the `.button2` anchor also has the bootstrap class of `hidden` so the anchor is no longer displayed. This is done in each of the product boxes depending on the need to have the second button for that product. I am not in control of this.
- When the `.button2` anchor has the `hidden` class I need to add some `margin-top` to `button1-container` to vertically center it

I was going to use pure style (flexbox) but it wasn't achieving what I needed.

I would like to run a little jQuery or pure JS every time the page finishes loading which adds some the top margin, if required, on each instance of this HTML. I don't like having to do this but will need to if I cannot find another simple way of controlling it.

Any thoughts... solutions... perfect solutions etc?

Thanks in advance!

cheers
wayjo

Comment: Could you create a [MRE] with the necessary CSS?

Comment: May I ask what the problem was with the flexbox solution?

Comment: @Turnip Thanks for responding, will try! I might have over simplified it to get to the crux of the problem.

Comment: @csba Thanks for responding! When i add display: flex to the container it wrecks the buttons. I would rather use it if I can but I couldn't figure.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I've fully understood your question.

You can achieve this without JS, in a cleaner any.
Why not make a custom class of button2-hidden and attach it to `all-buttons-container`?

```
<div class"all-buttons-container button2-hidden">
    <div class="button1-container">
        <a class="button1">text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button2-container">
        <a class="button2">text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you have this CSS:

```
.button2-hidden .button2-container{
  display: none; // or visibility -- whatever you want
}
.button2-hidden .button1-container{
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately I am not in control of the how the hidden class is added. Nice thinking though!

Comment: I can help you then. jQuery or vanilla JS ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a div to contain the buttons, than you can use the snippet below:

```css
.all-buttons-container{
  display: flex; /* important part */
  align-items: center;  /* important part */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  height: 150px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none!important;
}

.all-buttons-container > div a{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 7px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-buttons-container">
  <div class="very-important-div">
    <div class="button1-container">
        <a class="button1">button1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button2-container">
        <a class="button2">button2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="all-buttons-container">
  <div class="very-important-div">
    <div class="button1-container">
        <a class="button1">button1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button2-container">
        <a class="button2 hidden">button2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="all-buttons-container">
  <div class="very-important-div">
    <div class="button1-container">
        <a class="button1 hidden">button1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button2-container">
        <a class="button2">button2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```